# Creating array pair in php Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, loops, laravel, multidimensional-array

Hi is it possible to have an array structure like this

```
[1][2]
[4][7]
[3][6]
[9][5]
```

For example `[1][2]` is a single row value pair. `1` and `2` is an id value i want to store in an array. It's like saying that the partner of `1` is `2` and so on. If possible how do I assign or insert value in an array like that? Example I have this loop

```
foreach ($questions as $key => $value) 
{
    $mutuals = Mutual::where('question_id_1', '=', $value->id)->orWhere('question_id_2', '=', $value->id)->first();
    if(count($mutuals) >= 1)
    {
        // From here I want to put the first pair in the array
        // $mutuals->question_id_1 and $mutuals->question_id_2
    }
}
```

Comment: Pls add the tag for the framework you are using. (I guess, it's Laravel?)

Comment: @TareqMahmood sorry mate. Already added it. Yes it's Laravel

Comment: @JoeneFloresca sorry, I'm kind of confused, can you put some input, and the output you expect?

Comment: @mloureiro Hi sorry for the confusion. I am about to answer the question. I just change my logic and disregard this